# How to hide actual content in the page source

Tags: html, browser, web-scraping, response

Am trying to do hide the actual content in the page source. For example if user visits the first or second etc page via browser user can view different informations but when user visits the second page and right clicks and goes to page source user has to see only first page information. This should work for 'n' number of pages. I have many websites doing like this. I want to know how to do this. I want to avoid people from scraping my site. I want avoid actual data or information in the response. My Question is Is it possible to do this? If it is possible how to do? Please tell me am new to web domain.

Comment: They're called *obfuscators*, and they will require server-side technology, such as PHP or Perl, to scramble the message. I won't lecture you on the likelihood of it being overly effective; however, there are lots of products out there. [PHP Protect](http://www.phpprotect.info/index.php) is one, and free.

Comment: [ionCube](http://www.ioncube.com/sa_encoder.php) is a for-purchase one that seems popular, if you can make the cost-benefit analysis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't serve content to people and prevent them from scraping it.

What you probably mean is that many modern websites use AJAX to request information from the web server which is then used to modify the existing page. It would make scraping a bit more work but only mildly so. A determined person could still scrape the content from your website.

Comment: You can obfuscate the content sufficiently to deter some people, just not necessarily all. It depends whether web scraping bots are sophisticated enough to defeat it, something I'm not confident about with the more sophisticated obfuscation systems. How many "determined persons" are their really going after this site? Probably not a lot, so it's more than likely a wash either way. In the meantime, this answer I don't think is correct, as it's more of a rhetorical response, and not a factual response to "How to..."

Answer (score 0):

There is a long answer and a short answer to this commonly asked question.

The short answers is... **NO you cannot stop site scrapers**.

The long answer.. 
You really, really, really, really,really, really, really, really,
do not have a snowballs chance in hell of stopping a determined site scraper.

Once the page code enters the visitors web browser you lose all control over it.